# Can't read file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, readfile, streamreader

I am trying to write a piece of code, one of the things involved is reading from a .txt file line-by-line. However, I keep getting the 'An Object Reference is Required' error. I don't see how just reading a file could cause so many problems but it has. Here is my code (ignore the commented out bit just before the start):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
//(Program)
namespace FileReader
{
class ReadFromFile
{
    public void IsValidLine(string text)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^([A-Za-z]{1,5})((\s\d){0,9})(\s*)$");
        if (rgx.IsMatch(text) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Format");
        }

    }
    static void Main()
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new 
System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();


            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //HERE IS THE ERROR
                IsValidLine(line); 
                lines.Add(line);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `public void IsValidLine(string text)` to `public static void IsValidLine(string text)`. You need an instance of the `ReadFromFile` class to use the `IsValidLine` method when you don't have the `static` keyword. So just add the static keyword and you can figure out the details of what I just said later.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you access a non-static class in static context - therefore you needed a reference to an object of that class. So all you have to do is to make the method static:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
//(Program)
namespace FileReader
{
class ReadFromFile
{
    public static void IsValidLine(string text)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^([A-Za-z]{1,5})((\s\d){0,9})(\s*)$");
        if (rgx.IsMatch(text) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Format");
        }

    }
    static void Main()
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new 
System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();


            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //HERE IS THE ERROR
                IsValidLine(line); 
                lines.Add(line);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid such errors I'd suggest to make the class static as well:

```
static class ReadFromFile
//...
```

Then the code doesn't compile if anything isn't static in the class.

Comment: @GeorgeBouverie did this solve your problem? If it did so, don't forget to mark the answer as a valid answer, as this will help you and the wider community to identify solved problems.